# When are JavaScript statements executed?

Tags: javascript, runtime

I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>para 1</p>
    <p>para 2</p>
    <script>
      var allP = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
      for (var i = 0; i < allP.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        allP[i].onclick = function () {
          alert("p" + i + " was clicked."); // expected: i = 0..n-1; actual: i = n
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I open the console, I can see that the loop iterated over both paragraph tags: `0` and `1` are printed to the log.

When I click the first p tag, I would now expect to get an alert with the message "p**0** was clicked." What I get, however, is "p**2** was clicked."

Why? I'd assume that, when I pass `"p" + i + " was clicked."` to `alert`, `i` would get converted to a string - but it seems to be a reference to the Number object stored in `i` (that gets converted on the fly when the anonymous function is called) - which is, of course, `n` (i.e. `allP.length`) after the loop runs.

Can someone please explain to me what's going on (and when the argument to alert is "constructed"/evaluated), what this behaviour is called (I don't think a compiled language like Java, or an interpreted one like PHP3/4, would behave that way?), and what I'd need to do to get the behaviour I was expecting (i.e. have the alert message refer to the clicked element's index (without having to write each message out statically myself)).

Comment: This is a common duplicate: the listener has a closure to *i* in the function that assigns the listeners so it gets the final value of *i*, which is 2.

Comment: In a word, closures. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: OK. That's on the lesson plan for tomorrow, I think. As for duplicates, it's hard to find the right answer if you don't know what you are looking for... :) If it's already there, maybe we can close this one (with a link to a good answer)?

Comment: @AdmiralFailure—leads to a great trail of answers—duplicates of duplicates of duplicates… ;-)

Comment: @RobG - I know, spotted that just after I added the comment... Edited!